# How do i handle - (minus) symbol in EditBox android?

Tags: android, parsing, android-edittext, double

I Need to get a minus value in an EditText and process it and then need to display the resultant in another EditText. Everything works fine while parsing minus symbol program throws error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "-"
```

problem at

```
double CelVal=Double.parseDouble(CelText.getText().toString());
```

Comment: separate your edit text and then convert them into double .....

Comment: - is not a number. Just make it two edit text with number and one edit text for operator for simplify . Other wise with one edit text you need to solve it as an Expression using BODMAS.